# Is it possible to get beans by class type in Dagger2 similarly to Spring does?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Spring framework allows to get beans by class type in the following way:

```
ApplicationContext context;
Class<? extends Foo> fooClass;
Foo fooBean = context.getBean(fooClass);
```

Is there any way to achieve something similar to this with Dagger2?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only if you manually define a map multibinding over the class as a map key.

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    public MyClass() {}
}

@Module
public abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MyClass.class)
    public abstract Object bindMyClass(MyClass impl);
}
```

And then

```
@Inject
Map<Class<?>, Provider<Object>> providers;

MyClass myClass = (MyClass)providers.get(MyClass.class).get();
```

It'd be possible to restrict the key to `? extends MyClass` with custom keys.

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface FooKey {
    Class<? extends Foo> value();
}
```

Comment: That was my first approach, but multi-binding forces me to create an upper layer to manually generate those maps with dependencies I required. The idea is to extract dependencies from Dagger graph by reflection. In any case, thanks for your answer, I appreciated

Comment: @AlexTa Dagger won't provides anything in this sense as [its principle](https://dagger.dev/) is to have zero reflection.